# Is there a way to call and focus any popup window outside of the main window app?

Tags: python

I am trying to open a popup window when the user types something.

I read somewhere that Windows only allows you to focus a popup window if it has been called form the main window.

I search in the web and found this "work around", not very robust, because the methods to force focus were not working:

```
def bring_window_to_foreground(self):
       self.top_window.update_idletasks()
       hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Select Expansion")
       shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
       shell.SendKeys("%")
       time.sleep(0.1)
       shell.SendKeys("%")
       win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
       # Send another Alt key to nullify the activation
       self.top_window.focus_force()
```

But sometimes this wont work and apps the use "alt" key to show menus like notepad will have problemas sometimes.

Is there any library or windows api I can use to send my tkinter window to foreground, always on top and focused, withou calling it from the main window app, that will be minimized?

And one more question? How do I show this popup exactly on the same place or closer to the text cursor? I am using the code below, but is not working:

```
def get_caret_position(self):
        class GUITHREADINFO(ctypes.Structure):
            _fields_ = [("cbSize", ctypes.c_ulong),
                        ("flags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                        ("hwndActive", ctypes.wintypes.HWND),
                        ("hwndFocus", ctypes.wintypes.HWND),
                        ("hwndCapture", ctypes.wintypes.HWND),
                        ("hwndMenuOwner", ctypes.wintypes.HWND),
                        ("hwndMoveSize", ctypes.wintypes.HWND),
                        ("hwndCaret", ctypes.wintypes.HWND),
                        ("rcCaret", ctypes.wintypes.RECT)]
 
        guiThreadInfo = GUITHREADINFO(cbSize=ctypes.sizeof(GUITHREADINFO))
     
        hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
     
        processID = ctypes.c_ulong()
        threadID = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, ctypes.byref(processID))  # <-- Corrected line
     
        if ctypes.windll.user32.GetGUIThreadInfo(threadID, ctypes.byref(guiThreadInfo)):
            caret_x = guiThreadInfo.rcCaret.left
            caret_y = guiThreadInfo.rcCaret.top
            return caret_x, caret_y
        else:
            return None, None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dealt with the problem. This is my solution code:

```
def create_popup(tk_queue, key_listener_instance):
    print("Entered create_popup")  # Debugging
    while True:
        queue_data = tk_queue.get()
        msg, data = queue_data[:2]  # Only take the first two values
 
        current_window = getActiveWindow()
        current_win_title = current_window.title if current_window else "Unknown Window"
         
        if msg == "create_popup":
            print("About to stop listener and create popup")  # Debugging
            key_listener_instance.stop_listener()
 
            windows = gw.getWindowsWithTitle(current_win_title)
            if windows:
                main_win = windows[0]
                pyautogui.click(main_win.left + 10, main_win.top + 10)
            else:
                print(f"No window with title '{current_win_title}' found.")
 
            popup = ctk.CTk()  # Use ctk instead of tk
            popup.title("Select Expansion")
 
            for i, option in enumerate(key_listener_instance.expansions_list):
                raw_button_text = option['expansion'] if 'expansion' in option else "Undefined"
                button_text = truncate_text(raw_button_text, 60)
                button = ctk.CTkButton(
                    popup,
                    text=button_text,
                    command=partial(key_listener_instance.make_selection, i, popup),
                    font=("Work Sans", 12),
                    anchor="w"
                )
                button.pack(fill=ctk.X, padx=10, pady=5)
 
            # Update idle tasks to get updated dimensions
            popup.update_idletasks()
 
            # Get the content width and height
            content_width = 400
            content_height = popup.winfo_height()
 
            # Set the geometry of the popup to fit the content
            popup.geometry(f"{content_width}x{content_height}")
           
          
            def on_closing():
                try:
                    print("Trying to restart the listener...")  # Debugging
                    key_listener_instance.start_listener()  # Start the listener
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Failed to restart listener. Exception: {e}")
                finally:
                    popup.destroy()
 
            popup.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
            print("Setting WM_DELETE_WINDOW protocol")  # Debugging
 
            popup.attributes("-topmost", True)
            popup.focus_force()
 
            print("Entering Tkinter mainloop")  # Debugging
            popup.mainloop()
```